# Apex callout Unable to tunnel through proxy. 403 forbidden. Using Named Credentials; works fine in curl

Tags: callout, namedcredentials, calloutexception

**Given**:

- Apex Callout (POST) to an in-house REST service
- Named credentials
- Authorization headers are correct
- URL is correct
- Verified working using curl

**When**:

- Invoked using execute anonymous or invoked as part of a transaction

**Then**:

- Fails with `Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

The obvious answers that there's something wrong with the authorization header, endpoint, or HTTP method don't apply as I've checked up and down that values are correct - using same in curl

So, what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the clue here was the following:

- Service was an AWS ECS service
- The user testing with curl was the service owner of the REST service. Was not me.
- When I tried reproducing using a non-Named Credential setup - specifically Postman from my laptop, Postman timed out
- Service owner then admitted that the endpoint was accessible only to clients on the service's (AWS) VPN - and service owner's testing via curl was done on the VPN. My Postman testing was not done on the VPN
- Salesforce is obviously not on the in-house (AWS) VPN

Solution was for service owner to contact in-house DevOps and open up service to non-VPN client (Salesforce) via a reverse proxy.

*Bottomline - 403 Forbidden is typically, but not always a credentials issue*